How can I resolve this issue where my makeView call on NSTableView is always nil?
Can’t Make NSTableCellView in Programmatic UI NSTableView When calling makeView(identifier:owner:)
Hello all. I’m trying to put together a basic example of a NSTableView using programmatic UI instead of the storyboard, but I’ve run into a hiccup. When I call makeView(identifier:owner:) on the NSTableView object passed to the delegate method used to create the cells of the table, the call to makeView is always nil. Everything else works. I can navigate through the 30 rows I expected. All the columns show up, including their titles and headers. It’s just the data that won’t show because it won’t create cells. I can’t quite put my finger on why. I know the proper delegate method is being called because I checked with a print call. Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I’d rather not use bindings unless I absolutely have to.
My code looks like this (Yes I know it’s messy right now, but I just want to get it working first.):

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    var students: [Student] = []

    var tableView = NSTableView()
    var studentIdColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: .init("student_id_column"))
    var nameColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: .init("student_name_column"))
    var gpaColumn = NSTableColumn(identifier: .init("student_gpa_column"))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        students = createStudents(numberOfStudents: 30)
        
        configureUI()
    }
    
    private func configureUI() {
        configureTable()
        view.addSubviews([ tableView ])
        configureConstraints()
    }
    
    private func configureTableColumns() {
        studentIdColumn.width = 125
        gpaColumn.width = 125
        nameColumn.width = 550
        
        studentIdColumn.title = "Student ID"
        nameColumn.title = "Student Name"
        gpaColumn.title = "GPA"
        
        tableView.addTableColumn(studentIdColumn)
        tableView.addTableColumn(nameColumn)
        tableView.addTableColumn(gpaColumn)
    }
    
    private func configureTable() {
        configureTableColumns()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    private func configureConstraints() {
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    private func createStudents(numberOfStudents: Int) -> [Student] {
        let firstNames = Constants.firstNames
        let lastNames = Constants.lastNames

        var students = [Student]()
        
        for _ in 0..<numberOfStudents {
            let studentId = generateStudentId()
            let firstName = firstNames[Int.random(in: 0..<firstNames.count)]
            let lastName = lastNames[Int.random(in: 0..<lastNames.count)]
            let gpa = generateGPA()
            
            let s = Student(studentId: studentId, name: "\(firstName) \(lastName)", gpa: gpa)
            
            students.append(s)
        }
        
        return students
    }
    
    private func generateStudentId() -> String {
        var studentId = ""
        var isDuplicate = false
        
        repeat {
            studentId = String(Int.random(in: 100000..<1000000))
            isDuplicate = students.contains { student in
                student.studentId == studentId
            }
        } while isDuplicate
        
        return studentId
    }
    
    private func generateGPA() -> Double {
        return Double.random(in: 0..<5)
    }
    
    

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return students.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        guard let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) { return nil }
        
        if tableColumn!.title == "Student ID" {
            cellView.textField?.stringValue = students[row].studentId
        } else if tableColumn!.title == "Student Name" {
            cellView.textField?.stringValue = students[row].name
        } else {
            cellView.textField?.stringValue = getGPAFormatter().string(from: NSNumber(value: students[row].gpa))!
        }
        
        return cellView
    }
    
    private func getGPAFormatter() -> NumberFormatter {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        
        return formatter
    }
}


Did you read the documentation of makeView(withIdentifier:owner:)? It does what it says. If there are no reusable views then you have to create one. (NSTableView is a mess)

Does this answer your question? Is it possible to create a view-based NSTableView purely in code?

@Willeke Yes that worked but now I face an Index out of bounds error when adding a new row to the table. I updated the source of data by appending a new item, then called insertRows on the table. When there are no items in the table this happens. From all of the examples I've seen on it it shouldn't be doing that. Because it's not a batch of  updates, I'm not surround the insertRows call with beginUpdates() and endUpdates() like the docs say you don't have to.
